# Python programs hangs randomly

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie in python , so I was creating this project to create Sudoku using brute force method. To some extent I was successful but I am not able to figure out why sometimes the program hangs randomly while generating. Hope someone can pinpoint the issue.

I have tried debugging the code but still am not able to pinpoint what's causing the issue. The most close I have come to figuring something about the bug is that it is caused somewhere in the `brute_generator()` function.

A little Info on how the code is intended to work :-

The Sudoku is generated row by row by calling the `brute_generator()`function 9 times.

In the function `brute_generator()` the rows are generated using trial and error where a random number is picked up from possibilities list which is from number 1-9 and then it is treated as first number of row , now `check_1()` and `check_2()` function are called to check if the number has already been repeated in its column in previous rows if any and its **3x3** square as per the rules of Sudoku , if yes then the number is added to blacklist list and another number is chosen till the right number is obtained. When the right number is obtained it is appended to a `temp_array` while being removed from possibilities list so that it cannot be chosen again and counter is increased by 1 . This repeats till the row is generated  (i.e `counter = 9`) or no number from possibilities list can be placed in a given cell of row (i.e `len(blacklist)==len(possibilities)` , all possibilities are blacklisted) in which case the row being generated is scraped by returning all variables to their default values and a new row is generated . This happens until the perfect row is obtained which is then appended to `sudoku_array()`

```py
def check_1(x , temp_array ,  sudoku_array) :  # Check for recurrence in the Block in which the cell exist
    flag_1 = True
    if len(temp_array) < 3 :
        j = 2
        l = 0
    elif len(temp_array) < 6 :
        j = 5
        l = 3
    else :
        j = 8
        l = 6
    i = len(sudoku_array)
    if len(sudoku_array) < 3 :
        o = 0
    elif len(sudoku_array) < 6 :
        o = 3
    else :
        o = 6
    for m in range(o,i) :
        for n in range(l,j+1) :
            if x == sudoku_array[m][n] :
                flag_1 = False
                break
        if x == sudoku_array[m][n] :
            break
    return flag_1



def check_2(x, counter, sudoku_array) :  # Check for the recurrence of number in its consequent column
    flag_2 = True
    for k in range(len(sudoku_array)) :
        if x == sudoku_array[k][counter] :
            flag_2 = False
            break
    return flag_2



def brute_generator(sudoku_array) : # The main sudoku Generating Algo.
    all_possibilities = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    possibilities = all_possibilities.copy()
    blacklist = []
    counter = 0
    temp_array = []
    while counter != 9 :
        if len(blacklist) == len(possibilities) :
            all_possibilities = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
            possibilities = all_possibilities.copy()
            blacklist = []
            counter = 0
            temp_array = []
            continue
        x = random.choice(possibilities)
        if x not in blacklist :
            if len(sudoku_array) != 0 :
                if check_1(x, temp_array , sudoku_array) == False :
                    blacklist.append(x)
                    continue
                elif check_2(x, counter , sudoku_array) == False :
                    blacklist.append(x)
                    continue
            possibilities.remove(x)
            counter+=1
            temp_array.append(x)
            blacklist = []
    sudoku_array.append(temp_array)


sudoku_array = []   # This will be the generated sudoku
for i in range(9) :
    brute_generator(sudoku_array)
```

The Traceback calls show the following after the program is stuck

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 64, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 125, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1099, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1106, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\groot\source\repos\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5.py", line 145, in <module>
    brute_generator(sudoku_array)
  File "C:\Users\groot\source\repos\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5.py", line 109, in brute_generator
    x = random.choice(possibilities)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\random.py", line 255, in choice
    def choice(self, seq):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py", line 273, in __call__
    frame_cache_key = (frame.f_code.co_firstlineno, frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_code.co_filename)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Use Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break to break out, then include the full traceback that produces here in your question.

Comment: The issue is clearly with the while-loop (they're notorious for running forever). Without knowing how your brute generator works, the least I can say is: the logic flow of the while loop could use some improvement. Variable naming could also use some improvement (prefer descriptive names over placeholders such as `j`, `l`, `m`, `o`). Maybe it's just me, but it'll really help if you could edit the question and include how you intend the brute_generator function to work; outline the algo or something.

Comment: I have added a short description on how I wanted the brute_generator function to work . Can you also tell me how you figured that the problem was in the while loop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hope someone can pinpoint the issue.

The issue is that `for i in range(9) : brute_generator(sudoku_array)` can create a partial `sudoku_array` which is impossible to complete, e. g. the five rows:

```
[1, 5, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 9],
[9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 3, 1],
[4, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9, 7, 2, 5],
[5, 7, 9, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 8],
[6, 1, 3, 9, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4]
```

Now the function keeps searching for an appropriate sixth row which it never finds, and it never *backtracks*, which would mean throwing away previously generated rows to get out of the dead end.